# Count the number of cells in an Excel range using multiple criteria with wildcards

Tags: microsoft-excel, wildcards, countif

With Excel, when using the `COUNTIFS()` function with a single criteria, a wildcard value works just fine. Using the example data below, the following functions work as expected with my interesting data.

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B9, "A*") # 1
=COUNTIFS(B2:B9, "B*") # 2
```

However, when using multiple criteria, any use of a wildcard value results in `0`. In this test

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:A9, "AAA", B2:B9, "B*") # Expected 3, got 0
=COUNTIFS(B2:A9, "A*", B2:B9, "BBB") # Expected 3, got 0
=COUNTIFS(B2:A9, "<>A*", B2:B9, "<>B*") # Expected 5, got 0
=COUNTIFS(B2:A9, "C*", B2:B9, "D*") # Expected 5, got 0
```

My goal is to find the number of cells in a range that start with either `C`, or `D`. How can I do this with the `COUNTIFS()` function?

##### Example Data

| Name | Interesting Data |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | AAA |
| Name2 | BBB |
| Name3 | CCC |
| Name4 | BBB |
| Name5 | CCC |
| Name6 | DDD |
| Name7 | CCC |
| Name8 | DDD |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNTIFS function uses AND function when applied to multiple criteria as explained [here](https://exceljet.net/functions/countifs-function#:%7E:text=The%20COUNTIFS%20function%20is%20designed%20to%20apply%20multiple%20criteria%2C%20but%20conditions%20are%20applied%20with%20AND%20logic.):

> The COUNTIFS function is designed to apply multiple criteria, but conditions are applied with AND logic.

and [here](https://exceljet.net/functions/countifs-function#:%7E:text=Conditions%20in%20COUNTIFS%20are%20joined%20by%20AND%20logic.%20In%20other%20words%2C%20all%20conditions%20must%20be%20TRUE%20in%20order%20for%20a%20cell%20to%20be%20included%20in%20a%20count.%20The%20workaround%20above%20can%20be%20used%20in%20simple%20situations.)

> Conditions in COUNTIFS are joined by AND logic. In other words, all conditions must be TRUE in order for a cell to be included in a count. The workaround above can be used in simple situations.

To use it, as advised on the above links, join the criteria as shown below:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B2:B9; {"A*";"B*"}))
```

Comment: Thank you, I've got that working, although I did have to use a comma after the range, rather than a colon - `=SUM(COUNTIFS(B2:B9, {"A*","B*"}))`